# problem with centering vertically multirow

Tags: vertical-alignment, tabularx

can you please help me with this table. I tried many times to center vertically the last column but it doesn't work and even the space it's not good at all. I used the X (tabularx) but it seems not really managed by latex.If you have other teps To make my table look even good I will appreciated. thank you so much :)
ps: it's for a phd thesis

```
\documentclass[oneside,a4paper,12pt]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage{libertine}
   \usepackage{amsmath}
  \usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{emptypage} %prevents page numbers and heading appearing in empty pages
 \usepackage[french]{babel}
    \usepackage[top=3cm,bottom=2.5cm,left=2.5cm,right=2.5cm,headheight=26pt,headsep=25pt,heightrounded]{geometry}
 \frenchbsetup{FrenchFootnotes=false}  %more common footnote style
 \usepackage[hang,flushmargin]{footmisc} % footnote presentation
 \usepackage{enumerate}          % personnaliser les listes
   \usepackage[babel,french=guillemets]{csquotes}           
 \usepackage{graphicx}
  \setcounter{tocdepth}{5}     % level of sectionnin titles printed in TOC
  \setcounter{secnumdepth}{5} %sectionning titles are numbered: level 5
  \usepackage[titles]{tocloft} % nom du chapitre apparait en TOC
  \graphicspath{{\images}}
   \usepackage[dvipsnames,table]{xcolor}
  \usepackage{array,booktabs} 
  \usepackage{xfrac}
   \usepackage{refcount}
   \usepackage{tikz}
  \usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}
  \usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
  \usepackage{xspace}
   \usepackage{setspace}  %interligne 1.5
    \usepackage[parfill]{parskip}  % espace entre deux paragraphes
     \usepackage{calc}
     \usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
     \usepackage{shorttoc}
      \usepackage{enumitem} % modifier et personaliser les puces des listes
       \usepackage{pifont} % les symboles pour les listes
      \usepackage[french]{minitoc}
     \usepackage{etoolbox}
     \usepackage{sectsty}
    \allsectionsfont{\raggedright}
       \AtBeginEnvironment{footcitedquote}{\singlespacing\small}
       \AtBeginEnvironment{fancyquotes}{\small}
        %\setlength{\parskip}{10pt plus 1pt minus 1pt}}
      \setlength{\overfullrule}{5pt} % show the hfull and underfull vbox hbox warning

        \usepackage{smartdiagram}
          \usepackage{tabularx}
           \usepackage{multirow}

    % define colors
    \definecolor{c1}{rgb}{0,0,1}   %blue
     \definecolor{c2}{rgb}{0,0.3,0.9}   %light blue
      \definecolor{c3}{rgb}{0.3,0,0.9}   %red blue
        \definecolor{head}{RGB}{79, 129, 189}
        \begin{document}
            \begin{table}[!ht]
               \caption{\label{RCA} Les rôles du conseil d'administration}
              \centering
            \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{>{\columncolor[RGB]{79, 129, 189}}X|X|X}
           \toprule 
           \rowcolor{head}
           \multicolumn{1}{c}{\color{white}\textbf{\textsf{Théorie}}} &\multicolumn{1}{c}{\color{white}\textbf{\textsf{Rôle du conseil}}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\color{white}\textbf{\textsf{Trait dominant}}} \\
             \midrule
              \color{white} du capitalisme financier    & \cellcolor{head!10}Le conseil permet la cohésion du groupe et l'exercice du pouvoir. &\cellcolor{head!10}\\   
              \color{white} de la coordination/contrôle & Le conseil permet aux banques et aux familles de contrôle une société. & \multirow{3}{4.5cm}{\cellcolor{head!10}\textbf{Le conseil comme lieu d'exercice du pouvoir}} \\ 
      \color{white} de la cohésion sociale  & \cellcolor{head!10}Le conseil permet d'assurer la domination d'une classe sociale. & \cellcolor{head!10}\\
          \color{white} institutionnelle & Le conseil donne une image de la firme à son environnement. \newline Le conseil est un moyen pour l'entreprise de contrôler les ressources. & \textbf{Le conseil comme organe de médiation}\\    
          \color{white} légaliste & \cellcolor{head!10}Le conseil a pour vocation de protéger les intérêts des actionnaires. & \cellcolor{head!10}\\
         \color{white} managériale & Peu ou pas de rôle car le conseil est, de fait, manipulé par le dirigeant. &  \multirow{4}{4.5cm}{\cellcolor{head!10} \textbf{Le conseil comme lieu de contrôle}}\\
           \color{white} de l'agence &\cellcolor{head!10}Le conseil contrôle le dirigeant. & \cellcolor{head!10}\\
            \color{white} des coûts de transaction  &Gestion de la relation entre la firme, les actionnaires et les dirigeants. & \cellcolor{head!10}\\
           \bottomrule
            \hline
            \end{tabularx}

            \footnotesize Source: Le Joly (1998), Charreaux et Pitol-Belin (1990), Zahra et Pierce (1989)
               \end{table}
```

Comment: Do you want to centre vertically only the last column? Or also the first?

Comment: @Bernard yes why not! Thank you for your quick response :)

Comment: I've posted an answer without vertically centring the first column cells. If you want to have this feature, you simply have to redefine the `X` column type as `m{#1}` instead of `p{#1}` (details in the package documentation).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution: you had set as first parameter of `\multirow` the number of lines, not the number of rows, in the neighbouring cells. Also, instead of setting, more or less by trial and error, I suppose, the width of the multirow, as you're in a fixed width column, you can use `{=}` (this required slightly modifying the table preamble). To simplify a bit the code, I also used `\columncolor` for the last column. Last, I removed the thin white strips at the top and bottom of coloured cells, due to the vertical padding of the lines of `booktabs`, replacing it with `extrarowheight`. Loaded the  `caption` package, to have a decent spacing between caption and table, and incorporated the ‘Sources’ as a last row (looks better left-aligned, in my opinion).

*Unrelated*: I don't `sectsty` and `titlesec` are very happy together, and similarly for `enumerate` and `enumitem`.

```
    \documentclass[oneside,a4paper,12pt, french]{book}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \usepackage{libertine}
    \usepackage{amsmath}
    \usepackage{amssymb}
    \usepackage{emptypage} %prevents page numbers and heading appearing in empty pages
    \usepackage{babel}
    \usepackage[margin=2.5cm, top=3cm, headheight=26pt,headsep=25pt,heightrounded]{geometry}
    \frenchbsetup{FrenchFootnotes=false} %more common footnote style
    \usepackage[hang,flushmargin]{footmisc} % footnote presentation
    \usepackage{enumerate} % personnaliser les listes
    \usepackage[babel,french=guillemets]{csquotes}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \setcounter{tocdepth}{5} % level of sectionnin titles printed in TOC
    \setcounter{secnumdepth}{5} %sectionning titles are numbered: level 5
    \usepackage[titles]{tocloft} % nom du chapitre apparait en TOC
    \graphicspath{{\images}}
    \usepackage[dvipsnames,table]{xcolor}
    \usepackage{array,booktabs}
    \usepackage{xfrac}
    \usepackage{refcount}
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}
    \usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
    \usepackage{xspace}
    \usepackage{setspace} %interligne 1.5
    \usepackage[parfill]{parskip} % espace entre deux paragraphes
    \usepackage{calc}
    \usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
    \usepackage{shorttoc}
    \usepackage{enumitem} % modifier et personaliser les puces des listes
    \usepackage{pifont} % les symboles pour les listes
    \usepackage[french]{minitoc}
    \usepackage{etoolbox}
    \usepackage{sectsty}
    \allsectionsfont{\raggedright}
   \AtBeginEnvironment{footcitedquote}{\singlespacing\small}
   \AtBeginEnvironment{fancyquotes}{\small}
    %\setlength{\parskip}{10pt plus 1pt minus 1pt}}
    \setlength{\overfullrule}{5pt} % show the hfull and underfull vbox hbox warning

    \usepackage{smartdiagram}
    \usepackage{tabularx}
    \usepackage{multirow, caption}
    \setlength{\extrarowheight}{2pt}

% define colors
    \definecolor{c1}{rgb}{0,0,1} %blue
    \definecolor{c2}{rgb}{0,0.3,0.9} %light blue
    \definecolor{c3}{rgb}{0.3,0,0.9} %red blue
    \definecolor{head}{RGB}{79, 129, 189}

    \begin{document}
        \begin{table}[!ht]
           \caption{\label{RCA} Les rôles du conseil d'administration}
          \centering
        \setlength{\aboverulesep}{0pt}
        \setlength{\belowrulesep}{0pt}
        \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{>{\columncolor{head}}X|X| >{ \columncolor{head!10}\arraybackslash}X}%
       \toprule
       \rowcolor{head}
       \multicolumn{1}{c}{\color{white}\textbf{\textsf{Théorie}}} &\multicolumn{1}{c}{\color{white}\textbf{\textsf{Rôle du conseil}}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\color{white}\textbf{\textsf{Trait dominant}}} \\
       \arrayrulecolor{head!10} \midrule \arrayrulecolor{black}
          \color{white} du capitalisme financier & \cellcolor{head!10}Le conseil permet la cohésion du groupe et l'exercice du pouvoir. & \\
          \color{white} de la coordination/contrôle & Le conseil permet aux banques et aux familles de contrôle une société. & \multirow{3}{=}{\textbf{Le conseil comme lieu d'exercice du pouvoir}} \\
    \color{white} de la cohésion sociale & \cellcolor{head!10}Le conseil permet d'assurer la domination d'une classe sociale. & \\
      \color{white} institutionnelle & Le conseil donne une image de la firme à son environnement. \newline Le conseil est un moyen pour l'entreprise de contrôler les ressources. & \multirow{6}{=}{\cellcolor{white}\textbf{Le conseil comme organe de médiation}}\\
      \color{white} légaliste & \cellcolor{head!10}Le conseil a pour vocation de protéger les intérêts des actionnaires. & \\
     \color{white} managériale & Peu ou pas de rôle car le conseil est, de fait, manipulé par le dirigeant. &
     \\
       \color{white} de l'agence &\cellcolor{head!10}Le conseil contrôle le dirigeant. &\\
        \color{white} des coûts de transaction &Gestion de la relation entre la firme, les actionnaires et les dirigeants. & \multirow{-6}{=}{\textbf{Le conseil comme lieu de contrôle}}\\
       \bottomrule
        \hline
        \multicolumn{3}{@{}l}{\footnotesize Source: Le Joly (1998), Charreaux et Pitol-Belin (1990), Zahra et Pierce (1989)}
        \end{tabularx}

        \end{table}

        \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thank you so much bernard :) it looks very good as i wanted. As for your unrelated remarks how can i fix it do i have to eliminate one of the packages

Comment: Everything that enumerate does, enumitem can do it. As to  sectsty and titlesec, it depends on what you want to do with them.

Comment: ah ok as for sectsty and titlesec can do the same? sorry for my questions I'm new to latex

Comment: Can I ask you please a favor. Can I send you all my latex code for my thesis inculding macros....to see if I have somtehing Wrong in my packages....and your remarks especially about the page layout I really need someone to help me with that If it's ok I will really appreciated

Comment: Yes, of course. It would be probably simpler to send me a link to download your file(s).

Comment: Thank you so much it means a lot and do you have an email adress where I can send u that? for thet table issue, I tried your code everything works good but I don't get the vertical lines |X| and midrul

Comment: For the vertical rules, you have them, butas the colours slightly overlaps, your pdf viewer can hardly show them. You'll see them on zooming. However, if you want to see them with the default scaling, you replace `|` in the table preamble with `|!{\vrule width 1pt}`, or whatever thickness you please (default is 0.4pt). For \midrule, it is also there, but you can see it only at the bottom of the first column, because I changed its colour  to the paler shade of blue used  in the cells. For the email address, I'd prefer it remains private. But you can use something like WeTransfer or DropBox.

Comment: so even for the horizontal white lines?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/96097/discussion-between-bernard-and-alexia-colaud).

Answer (score 1):

Like this?

[image]

```
\documentclass[oneside,a4paper,12pt]{book}
\usepackage[skip=1ex]{caption}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
% define colors
\definecolor{c1}{rgb}{0,0,1}        % blue
\definecolor{c2}{rgb}{0,0.3,0.9}    % light blue
\definecolor{c3}{rgb}{0.3,0,0.9}    % red blue
\definecolor{head}{RGB}{79, 129, 189}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{booktabs, multirow, tabularx}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight}X}
\usepackage{copyrightbox}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[!ht]
\renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{m{#1}}
\caption{\label{RCA} Les rôles du conseil d'administration}
\centering
\copyrightbox[b]{\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{>{\columncolor[RGB]{79, 129, 189}\color{white}}L|
                             L|
                             >{\bfseries}L}
    \toprule
    \rowcolor{head}
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\color{white}\textbf{\textsf{Théorie}}}
    &   \multicolumn{1}{c}{\color{white}\textbf{\textsf{Rôle du conseil}}}
        &   \multicolumn{1}{c}{\color{white}\textbf{\textsf{Trait dominant}}} \\
    \midrule
du capitalisme financier
    &   \cellcolor{head!10}Le conseil permet la cohésion du groupe et l'exercice du pouvoir.
        &   \cellcolor{head!10}\\
de la coordination/contrôle
    & Le conseil permet aux banques et aux familles de contrôle une société.
        &   Le conseil comme lieu d'exercice du pouvoir \\
de la cohésion sociale
    & \cellcolor{head!10}Le conseil permet d'assurer la domination d'une classe sociale.
        &   \cellcolor{head!10}\\
%
institutionnelle
    &   Le conseil donne une image de la firme à son environnement.

        Le conseil est un moyen pour l'entreprise de contrôler les ressources.
            &   Le conseil comme organe de médiation    \\
légaliste
    &   \cellcolor{head!10}Le conseil a pour vocation de protéger les intérêts des actionnaires.
        &   \cellcolor{head!10}         \\
%
managériale
    &   Peu ou pas de rôle car le conseil est, de fait, manipulé par le dirigeant.
        &   \\
de l'agence
    &   \cellcolor{head!10}Le conseil contrôle le dirigeant.
        &   \cellcolor{head!10}
            Le conseil comme lieu de contrôle\\
des coûts de transaction
    &   Gestion de la relation entre la firme, les actionnaires et les dirigeants.
        &       \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
    }{Source: Le Joly (1998), Charreaux et Pitol-Belin (1990), Zahra et Pierce (1989)}
   \end{table}
\end{document}
```

Note: coloring cells and use of `booktabs` doesn't work well together.

**Edit:** 
partly considered your comment below, partly my note above:

```
\documentclass[oneside,a4paper,12pt]{book}
\usepackage[skip=1ex]{caption}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
% define colors
\definecolor{c1}{rgb}{0,0,1}        % blue
\definecolor{c2}{rgb}{0,0.3,0.9}    % light blue
\definecolor{c3}{rgb}{0.3,0,0.9}    % red blue
\definecolor{head}{RGB}{79, 129, 189}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{booktabs, cellspace, multirow, tabularx}
\setlength\cellspacetoplimit{4pt}
\setlength\cellspacebottomlimit{4pt}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight}X}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\Center}X}
\addparagraphcolumntypes{L}
\newcommand\mcbw[1]{\multicolumn{1}{>{\color{white}\bfseries\sffamily}Sc}{#1}}
\usepackage{boldline}
\usepackage{copyrightbox}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[!ht]
\renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{m{#1}}
\caption{\label{RCA} Les rôles du conseil d'administration}
\centering
\copyrightbox[b]{
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|>{\columncolor[RGB]{79, 129, 189}\color{white}
                             \hsize=0.8\hsize}L|
                             >{\hsize=1.2\hsize}SL|
                             >{\bfseries}C|}
    \hlineB{2}
    \rowcolor{head}
\mcbw{Théorie}
    &   \mcbw{Rôle du conseil} 
        &   \mcbw{Trait dominant}   \\
    \hlineB{1}
du capitalisme financier
    &   \cellcolor{head!10}Le conseil permet la cohésion du groupe et l'exercice du pouvoir.
        &   \cellcolor{head!10}\\
de la coordination/contrôle
    & Le conseil permet aux banques et aux familles de contrôle une société.
        &   Le conseil comme lieu d'exercice du pouvoir \\
de la cohésion sociale
    & \cellcolor{head!10}Le conseil permet d'assurer la domination d'une classe sociale.
        &   \cellcolor{head!10}\\
%
institutionnelle
    &   Le conseil donne une image de la firme à son environnement.

        Le conseil est un moyen pour l'entreprise de contrôler les ressources.
            &   Le conseil comme organe de médiation    \\
légaliste
    &   \cellcolor{head!10}Le conseil a pour vocation de protéger les intérêts des actionnaires.
        &   \cellcolor{head!10}         \\
%
managériale
    &   Peu ou pas de rôle car le conseil est, de fait, manipulé par le dirigeant.
        &   \\
de l'agence
    &   \cellcolor{head!10}Le conseil contrôle le dirigeant.
        &   \cellcolor{head!10}
            Le conseil comme lieu de contrôle\\
des coûts de transaction
    &   Gestion de la relation entre la firme, les actionnaires et les dirigeants.
        &       \\
    \hlineB{2}
\end{tabularx}
    }{Source: Le Joly (1998), Charreaux et Pitol-Belin (1990), Zahra et Pierce (1989)}
   \end{table}
\end{document}
```

- In both the MWEs above, I omit all packages from the preamble that I consider not relevant to the presented tables
- I add the packages `ragged2e` for formatting cells' content, `boldline` (from the shipunov bundle) for table rules, `cellspace` for more vertical space and `copyrightbox` for note below table about table source.
- With defined new column types and commands, I made table code slightly shorter and clearer.
- Different column width (in the second MWE) is obtained by using `\hsize=0.8\hsize` for the first column, and `\hsize=1.2\hsize` for the second. You can change those ratios (or even change for the third columns) according to your needs. You should ensure that the numbers accumulate to an integer number.
- I'm not sure, if the last column should be color `head!10`. If this is case, you just add `\columncolor{head!10}` to option of the last column and after remove all cell color commands from this column.

[image]

Comment: that looks good :) can u please make the text of the last column centered? And how can I get more space for the second column coz it has more text. I want the second column to be large than the others If you get what I mean

Comment: thatnk you so much for your help :)